# How to use sprintf in Url::fromUri?

Tags: 8

I am trying to convert this from D7 to D8:

```
l(drupal_strtoupper($field),
sprintf('http://finance.google.com/finance?q=%s',
$exchange . ':' . $field),
array('attributes' =>
array('target' => '_blank',
       'title' => (drupal_strlen($title)) ? $title : $field)
)
);
```

I am doing this and it produced error:

```
return Link::fromTextAndUrl(Unicode::strtoupper($field), Url::fromUri(sprintf('http://finance.google.com/finance?q=%s'),$exchange . ':' . $field))->toString();
```

> InvalidArgumentException: The URI '' is invalid. You must use a valid URI scheme. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri() (line 281 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to use `sprintf` (or any other string formatting/replacement functions) here - the API can already accommodate what you need in a much more structured manner:

```
$options = ['query' => ['q' => $exchange . ':' . $field]];
$url = Url::fromUri('http://finance.google.com/finance', $options);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(Unicode::strtoupper($field), $url);
```